# What is Qt Port?

Tags: qt

I came accross a website and what is this QTWebKit? and why do we use it and in which envoirment c++/Java or...

https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit#TechnicalArticles

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking "What is webkit?", "What is QT?", "What is porting?", "What is Open Source?", "Why is QT OpenSource?", "Why is webkit OpenSource?", "Why port Webkit to QT?" or some other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from your own link:

> WebKit is an open source web browser engine. [...] QtWebKit is a project aiming at porting this fabulous engine back to Qt.
>   The Qt port of WebKit currently compiles and runs on Linux (including Maemo and Meego), Windows, Mac OS X and Symbian."

So it's webkit ported to Qt. What Qt is, is described e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29).

A simple search also reveals the [Qt Webkit documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtwebkit.html).

Comment: It's high time to stop using trolltech.com domain for things related to Qt :)

Answer (score 1):

Citing the site you mentioned:

> WebKit is an open source web browser
>   engine. (...) QtWebKit is a project aiming at porting this fabulous engine back to Qt.

WebKit being an engine focused on implementing web browser's specific tasks (interpreting a web page's source (HTML, CSS), executing Java Script, creating visual representation and others) makes use of some basic services needed to accomplish these tasks. The examples of such services would be displaying an image on the screen or downloading a file over a network. These services must be provided for it to work. In case of Qt port these services are provided by Qt, which is a cross platform C++ framework for creating applications. You can find more information on Qt [here](http://qt.nokia.com/).